# Chrome extension - redirecting an https AJAX request to the same url in onBeforeRequest

Tags: ajax, google-chrome-extension, redirect

I am redirecting every request to the same url in `onBeforeRequest` listener using `redirectUrl` directive. It works fine with all sites as Chrome eventually send the request to the url. But I am loosing an AJAX request for one site (the request is not sent at all, e.g. **https://apiv2.abc.com/me?token=fiYoEdDLZxPJ...**). If I replace `return {redirectUrl: request.url};` with just `return`, everything is fine. Can I redirect every request to itself as the following? I tried this with and without `requestHeaders` permission. Your suggestions are needed please.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function interceptRequest(request) {
    if (request.tabId === -1) return;

     console.log("In before request: " + request.requestId + ", URL: " + request.url);

    return {redirectUrl: request.url};

}, {urls: ['*://*/*']}, ['blocking']);
```

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding your question. But, perhaps you could make sure you have the "requestHeaders" permission, which needs to be in the manifest in order to get request headers. I don't fully understand your question, but I suspect this may be related to whatever problem you're having.

Comment: @kzahel I included `requestHeaders` permission, but still not working. It is working fine with hundreds of request, but one AJAX request (upto my understanding). The site is working without extension.